# Is it possible to set observer(KVO) for a protocol instance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, protocols

Hi so I have a protocol called `DTNavigationControllerDataSource` which is defined as (leaving out the methods)

```
protocol DTNavigationControllerDataSource: NSObjectProtocol
```

Then, in my own custom `UINavigationController` subclass I have an instance variable of this protocol as follows.

```
var dataSource: DTNavigationControllerDataSource?
```

Basically I need to know when an object becomes the dataSource. i.e The `dataSource` property is set. So I can call the dataSource when it is initially set, to setup some state. I've thought about using KVO however `NSObjectProtocol` doesn't define any methods for doing so. I'm not sure if this is even possible or if there is an alternative way outside of using KVO to know when the dataSource property inside `DTNavigationController` is set. I've also tried `didSet` and `willSet` but Xcode threw errors at me, as I think that is only available for primitives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `didSet` approach should work fine actually, had no issue with the following code in a playground (Xcode 7 GM):

```
class DTNavigationController : UINavigationController {
    var dataSource: DTNavigationControllerDataSource? {
        didSet {
            print("new data source: \(dataSource)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh excellent, maybe I had the syntax wrong with the didSet. Thank you! That will help me quite a bit.